# AJAX app for pushing notifications

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am in need of some assistance with a test script I am writting. The point of the script is to have a page which pulls in records from the database using AJAX and displays them on the page.

How it works:

- Every 15 seconds it checks the database for new records.
- if new record is found it prints out a box with information on it
- The boxes must **queue** up and 'slide' up into the screen.
- A sound is played when they slide up and they must stay for 15 seconds before the next item in the queue displays

The issue:

I am not looking for code, i am just wondering how this would work architecturally. Like should I check for new records and add them to a global, then in a different function loop through the new records? But then how would I get it to stay on screen and play a sound per item?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: AJAX polling would work, but would increase server load dramatically as the number of users rises. Instead I would use websockets to instead 'push' notifications of a new record in the database to connected users.

Comment: Maybe worth asking this at https://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I meant to ask the question there rather than here; not on both. Apologies, I should have made that explicit in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather that writing this in vanilla js , have a look at angular. You will be able to to add to $scope variable and that gets rendered. Also it has some cool plugins for pagination. As far as sound goes. I am pretty sure that it is javascript and can be done with a function. Also angular provided $http which is simpler that writing ajax. But again this is just a suggestion. It can be done in vannila js also.
You can make a class and store the feeds in a list inside the class. And finally on startup create an instance of that class.

#### Better implementation

Because you specified ajax i didn't write about web sockets. But that would save you a lot of overhead on the server.